# Bones and armature render

Tags: rendering, bones, opengl

How can I make a simple animation render of an armature (to show all bones movements)?
This is an OpenGL render, but if i try the OpenGL animation render, the bones disappear.

[image]

Comment: I've just tested, mine opengl animation works. So be sure you don't have the option "Only Render" under Display in properties panel. Maybe you are pressing the animation button in a window where it's enabled? I can't think of other reasons

Comment: "Only render" was unchecked. Anyway, now it works, I didn't change anything. Mistery. Thank you, anyway.